# Using the MUI's SvgIcon with the "component" prop results in a blank page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js, material-ui

My code looks like this:

```
import DrawIcon from "frontend/public/svgs/draw.svg";

export default function SomeIcon(): JSX.Element {
  return <SvgIcon component={DrawIcon}/>
}
```

For some reason, whenever I use the `component` prop, the app renders a blank page and I get no errors.

I'm trying to use SVGR as shown in the [MUI documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/icons/#component-prop).

I'm making a Next.js app so I added this to my next.config.js file:

```
 webpack: (config) => {
   config.module.rules.push({
     test: /\.svg$/,
     issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
     use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
   });

   return config;
 },
```

And installed SVGR using `npm install @svgr/webpack --save-dev`.

I can't figure out why this happens or how to fix it.

Comment: is this path "frontend/public/svgs/draw.svg" correct?

Comment: @Yilmaz yes, I tried changing a character and got a runtime error. I also printed `DrawIcon` and it outputted (I assume) its data

Comment: check the chrome tools how that component is shown. and check the docs maybe it needs other props to make it visible